# Adding rows and updating following rows conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to add a row before certain condition in my data frame. In this case, every time Column "Days" is >= 3, I'd like to insert a row before.

The problem involves traveling from one city to another, so if the number of days between travels is >= 3 I'd like for that team to return to its home city, and then start the next travel from there. Therefore, the new row should reflect the correct coordinates for the home city, as well as to update the coordinates for the next trip (next row) since the team will be traveling from a different city.

Below is an example of the dataset

```
Date <- c("2017-10-20", "2017-10-22", "2017-10-25", "2017-10-26", "2017-10-27", "2017-11-01", "2017-11-03")
Team <-  c("Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A")
Opponent <- c("Opp 1 ", "Opp 2", "Opp 3", "Opp 4", "Opp 5", "Opp 6", "Opp 7")
Location <- c("Away", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Home", "Away", "Home")
City <- c("Opp 1 City",  "Opp 2 City", "Opp 3 City", "Opp 4 City", "Home City", "Opp 6 City", "Home City")
lat <- c(35.20, 40.67, 25.78, 41.84, 33.76, 40.01, 33.76)
lon <- c(-80.83, -73.94, -80.21, -87.68, -84.42, -75.13, -84.42)
destlat <- c(32.79, 35.20, 40.67, 25.78, 41.84, 33.76, 40.01)
destlon <- c(-96.77, -80.83, -73.94, -80.21, -87.68, -84.42, -75.13)
Days <- c(NA, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2)

df <- tibble(Date, Team, Opponent, Location, City, lat, lon, destlat, destlon, Days) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

df
```

And here a manually added solution of what the correct output should look like after adding the conditional row.

```
# desired output

Date <- c("2017-10-20", "2017-10-22", "2017-10-24", "2017-10-25", "2017-10-26", "2017-10-27", "2017-11-01", "2017-11-03")
Team <-  c("Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A")
Opponent <- c("Opp 1 ", "Opp 2", NA, "Opp 3", "Opp 4", "Opp 5", "Opp 6", "Opp 7")
Location <- c("Away", "Away", NA, "Away", "Away", "Home", "Away", "Home")
City <- c("Opp 1 City",  "Opp 2 City", "Home City", "Opp 3 City" ,"Opp 4 City", "Home City", "Opp 6 City", "Home City")
lat <- c(35.20, 40.67, 33.76, 25.78, 41.84, 33.76, 40.01, 33.76)
lon <- c(-80.83, -73.94, -84.41, -80.21, -87.68, -84.42, -75.13, -84.42)
destlat <- c(32.79, 35.20, 40.67, 33.76, 25.78, 41.84, 33.76, 40.01)
destlon <- c(-96.77, -80.83, -73.94, -84.42, -80.21, -87.68, -84.42, -75.13)
Days <- c(NA, 2, NA, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2)

df <- tibble(Date, Team, Opponent, Location, City, lat, lon, destlat, destlon, Days) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

df
```

Ideally looking for a dplyr solution but open to other options if needed.

Comment: In your example desired output, how did you decide that the date of the added row should be 2017-10-24? Is it the previous row's date + its number of travel days?

Comment: I forgot to explain that. I don't have a preference as long as it is a date between the previous and post date. In the example I used "2017-10-24" but "2017-10-23" would also work.

Comment: How did you determine lat/long should be 40.7, -73.9 for the added row? This isn't the same lat/long as the other locations given as Team A's "Home City". None of the three home city records for team A have the same lat/long.

Comment: Eric, apologies. I edited and corrected that

Comment: bcarlsen, the lat / lon for the home cities are always the same, what changes is the destlat/destlon which is taken from lag(lat) and lag(lon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for multiple teams:

```
# Create home team location df
Team <- c("Team A", "Team B")
lat <- c(33.8, 50)
lon <- c(-84.4, -90)
df_loc <- tibble(Team, lat, lon)

# function to create new row
new.row <- function(x) {
    Date <- x$Date - 1
    Team <- x$Team
    City <- x$City
    lat <- df_loc$lat[df_loc$Team == Team]
    lon <- df_loc$lon[df_loc$Team == Team]
    destlat <- x$destlat
    destlon <- x$destlon
    new_row <- tibble(Date = Date, 
                      Team = Team,
                      Opponent = NA,
                      Location = NA,
                      City = City,
                      lat = lat,
                      lon = lon,
                      destlat = destlat,
                      destlon = destlon,
                      Days = NA)
} 

# find the row where Days >= 3
row_loc <- which(df$Days >= 3)[1]

# call the function
new_row <- new.row(df[row_loc, ])

# add the row
df <- df %>% add_row(new_row, .before = row_loc)

# set the old Days (>=3) to 1
df$Days[row_loc +1] <- 1

df
```

Comment: This will also set the following row "Days" to 1.

Comment: Thank you Eric. That did return the correct outcome. One question, inside the function, Team, City, lat and lon are manually created. Is there a way to detect this automatically for each different team. The real dataset has 30 different teams with different "home city" and different lat and lon coordinates.

Comment: You can use your "Team" variable to determine that. You'll need to set up another data.frame to link Team with City, Lat and Lon

Comment: I've updated the answer to include multiple home teams

Comment: Thank you, this part seems to be throwing an error ```which(df$Days >= 3)[1]``` I believe it is due to having more than one row where the condition applies when working with multiple teams. The actual error I get ```Error in vec_rbind(old, new) : Internal error in `vec_proxy_assign_opts()`: `proxy` of type `double` incompatible with `value` proxy of type `NULL`.```

Comment: `df$Days` returns a vector, and strips everything else out, and the `[1]` will select only the first result in the vector. So the `Team` column isn't the issue. I can't reproduce this error. Check your `Days` column carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant of solutions, but what I did is I created the new rows that are needed by modifying existing rows in a filtered dataframe, and then bound them back with everything else.

```
bind_rows(
  filter(df,Days>=3) %>% mutate(destlat="33.76", destlon="-84.42"),
  filter(df,Days>=3 & lag(Location!="Home")| lead(Days>=3) & Location!="Home") %>% 
    mutate(Date=lag(Date)+lag(Days), Location="Home",City="Home City",destlat=lag(lat),destlon=lag(lon),lat="33.76",lon="-84.42",Opponent=NA) %>% 
    filter(Days>=3) %>% 
    mutate(Days=NA),
  filter(df,Days<3)) %>%
  arrange(Date)

# A tibble: 7 x 10
  Date       Team   Opponent Location City       lat   lon    destlat destlon  Days
  <date>     <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 2017-10-22 Team A Opp 2    Away     Opp 2 City 40.67 -73.94 35.20   -80.83      2
2 2017-10-24 Team A NA       Home     Home City  33.76 -84.42 40.67   -73.94     NA
3 2017-10-25 Team A Opp 3    Away     Opp 3 City 25.78 -80.21 33.76   -84.42      3
4 2017-10-26 Team A Opp 4    Away     Opp 4 City 41.84 -87.68 25.78   -80.21      1
5 2017-10-27 Team A Opp 5    Home     Home City  33.76 -84.42 41.84   -87.68      1
6 2017-11-01 Team A Opp 6    Away     Opp 6 City 40.01 -75.13 33.76   -84.42      5
7 2017-11-03 Team A Opp 7    Home     Home City  33.76 -84.42 40.01   -75.13      2
```

Comment: (sorry, fixed a couple of mistakes there)

Comment: Thank you. That seems very close.  That solution removed the first row ("2017-10-20"), which I'd like to keep. Also, is there a way to avoid adding a manual mutate? since the real data frame has thousands of rows and different teams.

Comment: sorry, it should be `filter(df,Days<3 | is.na(Days)`. I'm not sure about your second question - the team name stays the same, the mutate only applies to those things that change when you move to Home, the rest will stay the same.

Comment: the real dataset has 30 different teams, each with different lat and lon coordinates. It looks like you are manually creating destlat and destlon within the mutate statement, but I am wondering if those can be set programmatically